# Using C#, how can I determine the Server Message Block version?

Tags: c#, network-protocols, smb

I would like to determine the network protocol (Server Message Block, version 1 or 2) using C#.

Is there anybody who knows how to do that?

Comment: "the" network protocol? *Which* network protocol? Have you already captured some packets? Do you want to know which protocol a particular server supports? Your question is too vague at the moment.

Comment: @Jon - SMB most likely, from the tag.

Comment: @vcsjones: Yes, I realise it's SMB - but what information do we have to go on? That's like saying "I would like to determine the network protocol (HTTP or HTTPS) using C#" - how would you go about doing that, with *no more information*? There's simply no context. Is it "the network protocol supported by this server" or "the network protocol present in these packets" or "the network protocol in this URL" etc.

Comment: Without going out and figuring this out on my own, you may want to consult the SMB and SMB2 specifications? I'm sure there exists some library (even in the base class library?) that should handle this for you. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc246482%28PROT.10%29.aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee442092%28PROT.10%29.aspx